# Android - list scrolling without the other elements on the page

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity where I display a list of comments and then display a text area for people to add more comments.

Right now if there are a few comments that reach the bottom of the screen, it is over-written by the text area.

What I would prefer is if the entire page was scrollable together with the comments and the text area.

Here is my current layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >         

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >    

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question_label"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your question: "
    />     

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    />     

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/please_wait"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Please wait while the discussion loads..."
    />     

    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >        
    </ListView>

        <EditText  
            android:id="@+id/question_text"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:hint="@string/question_comment_hint"  
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"  
            android:lines="5"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
        </EditText>

<Button  
            android:id="@+id/submit"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="@string/submit"  
            android:onClick="sendFeedback"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
        </Button>               

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: If I had to scroll all the way to the bottom every time to leave a comment I would be one frustrated user :). Why don't you put your edittext and button outside of the scrollview, that way a user can add a comment at any point while looking through the list?

Comment: You shouldn't have a listview inside a scrollview.

Comment: Agreed with @Jack. I think you should have a menu option or action bar option (depending on what version of android you are building for) that is a "new comment" option that will bring up a dialog for you that allows you to enter a new comment

Comment: I added an answer on how to do it, but I agree that for most cases, the best choice concerning the user experience would be to use "New comment" in actionbar

Comment: whats the action bar? you mean as a menu item?  I am thinking to maybe leave the text area on top and let the user scroll through the items below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use footer in your listview (`view.setFooterView()`). It's explained [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#miscellaneous_headerfooter).

And don't use both listview and scrollview at the same time. Listview is completely sufficient here.